# Invoke a method when the underlying value of a ref returning property changes

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Consider the following code:

```
public struct Vector2
{
   public float X;
   public float Y;
}

public class Sprite
{
   private Vector2 position;
   public ref Vector2 Position => ref position;

   private void DoStuffWhenPositionChanges() { /*...code...*/ }
}
```

The `ref return` allows me to do the following set operations:

```
someSprite.Position.X++;
someSprite.Position.Y = 42;
```

I would like to invoke `DoStuffWhenPositionChanges` whenever either the `X` or `Y` components of the `Position` struct are set. Note, `Vector2` is a library-level struct, and cannot be changed in my code.

I am looking for a solution similar to:

```
public class Sprite
{
   private Vector2 position;
   public Vector2 Position
   {
      get => position;  //ref return not possible!
      set
      {
         position = value;
         DoStuffWhenPositionChanges();
      }
   }

   private void DoStuffWhenPositionChanges() { /*...code...*/ }
}
```

...but with a `ref return`, to avoid having to do the following in the calling code:

```
someSprite.Position = new Vector2(someSprite.Position.X, someSprite.Position.Y + 1);
```

I've considered `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but as I cannot modify the library-level `Vector2` struct, I need an alternative solution. I also considered a proxy type, implicitly convertible to Vector2, that would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but that seems ...cumbersome; perhaps there's a cleaner solution I am not aware of.

Is it possible to know when the underlying value of the `ref return` property changes, given the above setup?

Comment: Why not implement a `Translate()` method?

Comment: What framework/library is `Vector2` from? I don't think what you're asking for is possible, but the framework might provide, for example, a "moved" event that would give you similar information.

Comment: Framework/library is not really relevant, as I'm looking for a more general solution (same goes for implementing `Translate()` method). This very specific example is MonoGame framework; I did not tag MonoGame, as it just happens to be a context for my question. In this very specific case, I can provide pass-through properties for X and Y components; but it will not apply to a larger struct. The example I provided happens to be [mcve] for this problem.

Comment: It's a bit like trying to know what some other piece of code is doing with *its* variables after you've provided a response from a method. Outside of debugging scenarios (e.g. data breakpoints), you don't get to find out.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a wrapper for Struct and then implement `RaisePropertyChanged` method or `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public struct Vector2
{
   public float X;
   public float Y;
}

public class VectorWrapper
{
   private Vector2 thing;
   public var X 
   {
        get { return thing.X; }
        set { thing.X = value; RaisePropertyChanged(SomePropertyName); }
   }
   public var Y 
   {
        get { return thing.Y; }
        set { thing.Y = value; RaisePropertyChanged(SomePropertyName); }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned the proxy type idea in my question, but the issue with it is anything that takes a `Vector2` now has to deal with the wrapper... even with implicit conversions, it's a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack but this will get the job done.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = new Sprite();
    s.DoStuffWhenPositionChanges(s.Position.X++);

}

public struct Vector2
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
}

public class Sprite
{
    private Vector2 position;

    public ref Vector2 Position => ref position;

    public void DoStuffWhenPositionChanges(float f = default)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, although functionally equivalent to just running the method after each change, as the method would have access to the data at that point.

Comment: Yep. It's unfortunate but ye, you can't have setter on ref return property.